# Complete missing values in a column or how to create values between a given range from a single variable

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I've a list of species distributed along an elevation gradient, but only the upper and lowest limits. I want to complete the missing information between the extreme, so can map the species distribution.

[here are the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ba1BoqYWYm9UQ_hhsI30N05ueY--WPCJ/view?usp=sharing)

| species | range | elevation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| spp1 | upper | 1100 |
| spp1 | lower | 100 |
| spp2 | upper | 20 |
| spp2 | lower | 1200 |
| spp3 | upper | NA |
| spp3 | lower | 900 |
| spp4 | upper | 500 |
| spp4 | lower | 0 |
| spp5 | upper | NA |
| spp5 | lower | 900 |

*elevation 0 indicate sea level and NA when only one data was available for the species

I tried with pivot_wider and then back to the long version, but my best was with the function complete()

```
df %>%
  complete(spp, elevation= seq(0,3500,100), fill = list(Value = NA))
```

For every species sequences I assumed an elevation range from 0 to 3500 m.asl  and fill the presences of the species every 100 m elevation. This worked, but I lost several species. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pivot wider to get each species in its own row, then group by species, then use a multi-group summarize:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.csv("listSpp.csv")

df %>% 
  mutate(spp = factor(spp, unique(df$spp))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = limits, values_from = elevation, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(lower, upper)) %>%
  mutate(lower = ifelse(is.na(lower), upper, lower),
         upper = ifelse(is.na(upper), lower, upper)) %>%
  group_by(spp) %>%
  summarise(Elevation = seq(0, 3500, 100),
            present = lower <= seq(0, 3500, 100) &
                      upper >= seq(0, 3500, 100),
            .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 147,096 x 3
#>    spp                                 Elevation present
#>    <fct>                                   <dbl> <lgl>  
#>  1 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey         0 FALSE  
#>  2 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey       100 FALSE  
#>  3 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey       200 FALSE  
#>  4 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey       300 FALSE  
#>  5 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey       400 FALSE  
#>  6 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey       500 FALSE  
#>  7 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey       600 FALSE  
#>  8 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey       700 FALSE  
#>  9 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey       800 TRUE   
#> 10 Isoetes araucaniana Macluf & Hickey       900 TRUE   
#> # ... with 147,086 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, but it seems that in your example you also lost species, as I did.... first species are Isoetes in the original data. That's weird!!

Comment: @RicardoMoreno they are there - it's just that the species column is sorted differently. If you run the above code and store the result in `df2`, then you will find the isoetes in rows `df2[71965:72108,]`

Comment: I've updated to show a method that preserves the species order